# CSharpMath.Forms in Windows Application How to Use?

Tags: c#, math

I just want to show a integral question via a label (`lblQuestion.Text = ;`) but have no idea how to use this NuGet class CSharpMath and couldn't find any documentation that was useful or at least that I could understand. I want to write a integral to ask the user to solve (e.g. using integration by parts, solve:  (integral symbol) (xlnx)dx).

If anyone knows how to use this class and/or a better way to write maths function in text that that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

CSharpMath.Forms does not allow you to display Maths in a label although it provides its own custom view as show in these examples from the [github repository](https://github.com/verybadcat/CSharpMath):

C#:

```cs
var view = new CSharpMath.Forms.MathView();
view.HorizontalOptions = view.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
view.LaTeX = @"\frac\sqrt23";
someLayout.Children.Add(view);
```

XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:math="clr-namespace:CSharpMath.Forms;assembly=CSharpMath.Forms"
             x:Class="Namespace.Class">
    <math:MathView x:Name="View" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        \frac\sqrt23
    </math:MathView>
</ContentPage>
```

So you need to replace your Label ("lblQuestion") with a MathView as shown in the examples and set its contents using LaTeX / MathTex ([examples of LaTeX math](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of CSharpMath and what you described can be displayed with a `CSharpMath.Forms.TextView`. You can't do it with a `Label` because it only supports normal text.

For the text `using integration by parts, solve: (integral symbol) (xlnx)dx`, you can use this:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:math="clr-namespace:CSharpMath.Forms;assembly=CSharpMath.Forms"
             x:Class="Namespace.Class">
    <math:TextView x:Name="View" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        Using integration by parts, solve: $\int\left(x\ln x\right)dx$
    </math:TextView>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Displayed output]

You can ask on [GitHub](https://github.com/verybadcat/CSharpMath) directly, you will get a much quicker response than on StackOverflow :)